# Mongo indexes are not being used when add one more property

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I'm running two different queries to my database, however, one is running really fast, calling/using all relevant indexes, and the other one, which just adding one more field to search on, is super slow. Please let me know if you have any idea how to solve it.

This one is running super fast:

```
db.orders.find(
{
        '$or': 
            [ 
                { order_id: { '$regex': '^.*8664149', '$options': 'i' } }, 
                { ref_number: { '$regex': '^.*8664149', '$options': 'i' } }, 
                { 'ls.ref_order_number': { '$regex': '^.*8664149', '$options': 'i' } }, 
                { tracking_number: { '$regex': '^.*8664149', '$options': 'i' }}, 
                { 'customer.first_name': { '$regex': '^8664149', '$options': 'i' } }, 
                { 'customer.last_name': { '$regex': '^8664149', '$options': 'i' }  } 
                 ]
        })
```

However, this one, where i also search on retailer name, is running very slow and its also not calling the index that i created on the retailer field:

```
db.orders.find(
{
        retailer: ObjectId("57a8d0b9eb656789de793"),
        '$or': 
            [ 
                { order_id: { '$regex': '^.*8664149', '$options': 'i' } }, 
                { ref_number: { '$regex': '^.*8664149', '$options': 'i' } }, 
                { 'ls.ref_order_number': { '$regex': '^.*8664149', '$options': 'i' } }, 
                { tracking_number: { '$regex': '^.*8664149', '$options': 'i' }}, 
                { 'customer.first_name': { '$regex': '^8664149', '$options': 'i' } }, 
                { 'customer.last_name': { '$regex': '^8664149', '$options': 'i' }  } 
                 ]
        })
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: Add query plans with execution stats to the question.

Comment: Also, please specify what are the indexes you have defined on the `orders` collection.

Comment: That's not just adding one field to the query.  That is also adding a new `and` operation and demoting the `or` operation from top-level to nested.  [Explain](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.explain/index.html#db-collection-explain) can help you determine why it takes so long.